# Building anagram finder and I have one eclipse error: insert } to complete block.

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, curly-braces

Problem is that the eclipse recommendation makes little sense -- to me. I checked my blocks several times.

This is my first time posting code so I'm hoping it's formatted ok.
The eclipse error is on line 73: below the ;  "anagrams.add(current);" This is the second line below the last for loop in the code.

```
package anagrecur2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.*;

public class AnagRecur2Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> anagrams = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> preString = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> postString = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> word = new ArrayList<String>();
        word.add("t");
        word.add("e");
        word.add("a");
        word.add("m");
        preString.add("");
        postString.add("");
        String c;
        String current;

    }
        ArrayList<String> getAnagrams (String word, String preString){

            // remove the first occurrence of each
            // character in preString from word and
            // stores it in postString  
        }
            ArrayList<String> removePreStringFromWord(List word){
            ArrayList<String> postString;
            ArrayList<String> preString;

            for (int i = 0; i < preString.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < word.size(); j++) {
                if (preString.get(i)== word.get(j)){
                    word.remove(j);
                }else { 
                    postString.add((String) word.get(j));
                    }
                }
                return postString;  
            }
        }

        // using a string as if it is a c# string.
        // for java you need to convert the string to
        // char array

        //ArrayList<String> word;
        //String current;
        //char poststrCharA;
        ArrayList<String> anagrams;
        ArrayList<String> preString;
        ArrayList<String> postString;

        String[] prestrAr = new String[preString.size()];{
        prestrAr = preString.toArray(prestrAr);

        for(String s : prestrAr){
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        for (String poststrCharA : postString){
            poststrCharA.toCharArray();
            System.out.println("postStringtoCharAr"+poststrCharA);
            }
        // adds string combo to anagrams if
        // it is a true word
        for (String c : prestrAr) {
            String current = prestrAr + c;
            anagrams.add(current);
        }

            void getAnagrams(char word, char current){
                System.out.println("word= "+word+"current= "+current);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, your getAnagrams doesn't return a string Array list. Also, what are you trying to accomplish with this file?

Comment: Jason thanks for looking over my code. I have since restructured several parts and added functionality. Don't have need to review this program further.